# How can I achieve a fixed vertical position for titlegraphic on custom title page?

Tags: beamer, positioning, themes

How can I achieve a fixed **vertical** position of the blue "logo", **even if** author or institute or subtitle *contain more than 1 line*?

[image]

Right now, if I add a second line to any of the content elements, every element on the title page moves. I thought that the slide's total content height was fixed, and that the two `\vfill`s would "uncouple" the `\titlegraphic` from the remaining content.

### The code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Custom title page
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{ 
  \vskip-0.59cm%
  \hskip-.7cm%
  \inserttitlegraphic%
  \vfill%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=6pt]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=6pt]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=6pt]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=6pt]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
}

% Custom logo
\newcommand\MyLogo{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
  \path[fill=blue,nonzero rule] 
  (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
  % more; generated by Inkscape...
\end{scope}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\titlegraphic{\resizebox{!}{.6cm}{\MyLogo}}

\title{Foo is a Bar}
\subtitle{More subtitle}
\author{Authorname}%\\2nd authors,\dots}
\institute{Awesome institute}
\date{Winter 1999}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

### How to reproduce my issue

Just uncomment the `%\\2nd authors,\dots` part in the `\author` line in the preamble. With that, the blue logo will move upwards towards the paper border. I would like to achieve a fixed position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\begin{frame}[t]
\maketitle
\end{frame}
```

and remove `\vskip-0.59cm%` so that the frame starts from top.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Custom title page
\setbeamertemplate{title page}
{
  %\vskip-0.59cm%
  \hskip-.7cm%
  \inserttitlegraphic%
  \vfill%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=6pt]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=6pt]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=6pt]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=6pt]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
}

% Custom logo
\newcommand\MyLogo{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
  \path[fill=blue,nonzero rule]
  (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
  % more; generated by Inkscape...
\end{scope}%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\titlegraphic{\resizebox{!}{.6cm}{\MyLogo}}

\title{Foo is a Bar}
\subtitle{More subtitle}
\author{Authorname\\2nd authors,\dots}
\institute{Awesome institute}
\date{Winter 1999}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\maketitle
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```